# configuring wampserver after installation to enable ssl

Tags: php, apache, ssl, wampserver

I installed wampserver with Apache v2.2.17 and PHP v5.3.5.
When I use the function `file_get_contents()` with the HTTPS URL as a parameter, I get the following warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents()
>   [function.file-get-contents]: Unable
>   to find the wrapper "https" - did you
>   forget to enable it when you
>   configured PHP? in
>   C:\wamp\www\fbapp\index.php on line 22

Is there a way to configure wampserver to enable SSL without reinstalling it?

Comment: You can use [cURL functions](http://php.net/curl) for SSL requests.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I looked it up and you should:

1. Check `ssl_module` in the Apache modules.
2. Check `php_openssl` in the PHP extensions.

Working! :)

Answer (score 0):

And check one more thing:

It may give an error if the file is not found as well. So use this one:

```
$f=@file_get_contents(path);

if($f){
    // your code here...
}
```