# php google calendar integration dummy exception

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm totally new to php, et I have to accomplish small project in few days. For the moment my problem is I can't integrate my php scripts with google calendar. I'm using Zend framework and I'm doing everything like in this(http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/) tutorial. I'm getting strange exception:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Unable to Connect to ssl://www.google.com:443. Error #156366088: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?'
```

What could that be? I'm sorry if it's a nooby question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you need t enable ssl - it's easy, simply uncomment (remove the ;) from `extension=php_openssl.dll` in your `php.ini`

If you're using WAMP: [configuring wampserver after installation to enable ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774182/configuring-wampserver-after-installation-to-enable-ssl)

Comment: I've got this the same evening I posted this answer:) Thanks anyway for response, your answer is correct